# How to zoom in a web browser on an Android TV?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, zooming, android-tv

I have a TV that runs Android 2.2. It can take a USB mouse and keyboard, and I'm running the Dolphin web browser on an auto-refreshed page for digital signage.

Only thing is, I can't get it to zoom in or out - there is no touch (so multitouch doesn't work) and there are no +/- buttons as there are on some stock browsers.

The stock browser doesn't work on the site in questions, and Firefox won't load onto the device (it has a MIPS processor, so any app using the native SDK won't work). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purchase a mouse which supports multitouch gestures (using which you zoom in or out). e.g. [PadKite](http://padkite.com/)

If you don't want to purchase anything, just go to Dolphin's `Settings`, tap `Lab` and turn ON `pinch-Zoom Button`. Then, you'll find +/- clickable buttons to zoom in or out.